# How do I select pandas row if a column in that row contains a substring present in a list

Tags: python, pandas

So if my pandas df has two columns, Countries and places:

```
  Countries     Places
0        US   New York
1        UK   Old York
2    France      Paris
3     India  New Delhi
```

I have a list like so: `l = ['New','Old']`

How would I select rows for which the places column contain text that contain string that is also present in my list.
(The whole string may or may not be present in the list)
(It should create a data frame that only contains, US, UK, India but NOT france).
(It will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.contains`

```
l = ['New', 'Old']
out = df[df['Places'].str.contains('|'.join(l))]
print(out)

# Output
  Countries     Places
0        US   New York
1        UK   Old York
3     India  New Delhi
```

Note: `str.contains` search in whole string. If you want to limit the search to the start of string, use `str.match` instead.

Comment: I was giving my two cents with a regex, but I saw your answer. Wouldn't it be better to use `startswith` instead of `contains`?

Comment: @vaeVictis. You probably right but I don't know if some places around the world end by 'New' or 'Old' :) Note you can also use `str.match`

Comment: In fact, you can't @vaeVictis. `startswith` does not accept a regex pattern but `match` works.

Comment: @Corralien My bad, I made confusion, but I was suggesting an overcomplicated solution. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AdiKrish. Does it solve your problem?